# How do I choose a different support email address when registering a Google OAuth app?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I'm a domain admin for a Gsuite account, and I'm attempting to create a GCP app that will be used solely to obtain permissions to connect to a Google user's account, a regular social sign-in. When defining the app, it asks for a user support email address:

[image: GCP app info form]

The problem is that it won't let me enter a free-form address, only select the address I'm logged in to GCP console with. I don't want my personal admin account to be used for public purposes, so I need to select some other address in my domain. This support address is used to forward to another address, and does not have a full account of its own, so I can't log in as that user.

How can I get it to allow me to select any defined address or alias in the domain, and not just mine?

This isn't strictly a programming question, however, Google's documentation points here as their primary support channel.